# Does a charging cable connected to a wall mount (which is turned on) but not to any device use electricity?

Tags: power-supply

I always assumed it does but after learning appliances only draw as much power as they need, I'm not so sure anymore.

Comment: To be pedantic, the cable itself draws no power. The power adapter that you plug in to a wall socket and to which the cable attaches to does consume a small amount of power even when idle.

Comment: If it's literally just cable, it will draw no power. If the "charging cable" (for example) converts AC to DC, monitors charging current, shows red or green lights, and shuts off if it thinks there's a fault (etc) then it'll draw a tiny amount of power to keep all of that alive ... a few watts or maybe less than a watt..

Comment: @user_1818839 Well, to be overly pedantic, even "literally just cable" will draw a minuscule amount of power due to the cable's parasitic capacitance and nonzero resistance, but that's going to be down in the nanowatts i'm sure.

Answer (score 4):

The power a charger device draws can crudely be divided into three portions

- The power needed for the load. In a well designed device, this is the largest part by far.
- The losses involved in charging the load. These increase as the load increases, and are mostly as a result of losses in inductors, transformers and power devices that need to carry the current to the load. You might hope for losses of less than 5% in a well designed device, but they will often be more, 10% is common and 20% is not unheard of. These losses are why a charger runs hotter when working than when idle.
- The power required to operate the charger, load or no load. This portion need not be large at all, but it costs design time and money to make it very small, and it's the user (and the climate) paying for the power used, not the equipment manufacturer. There is therefore little incentive for the designer to make it really small, but just to meet legislation in parts of the world where it is going to be used. Below 1 watt is a common specification today, but older devices would often draw a lot more.

Answer (score 2):

There can be some minimal current to keep the circuitry operational. But it's so small I doubt it can have any noticeable effect on your power bill. We're talking about 1mA or less usually, some converters need a supply of literally a few dozen microamps, as far as I know. Sometimes these adapters can have an LED which takes another 1-2mA.

But yes, the devices pull as much current as they need, that is true and never changed. It's just that the converting circuitry needs to consume tiny bit as well, so it pulls as much as it needs too. Which is very-very little, but not zero.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Plugged in devices consume some amount of power, there is no way around that. How much is another thing, they are required to have some efficiency level by legislation, but older devices draw more power when idle. Leaving it connected to mains can shorten the life of the device and it might be a fire hazard - but that goes to all devices.